# How can I create a role with privileges to drop tables in PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql

I need to create separate role which will have the privilege to drop a table. The problem is that the database contains more than 1000 tables.
Is there any way to change the privileges(add the new role) for all the tables at once without doing it for each one of them manually?

Comment: Is this a question about privileges or about dropping 1000 tables with one statement?

Comment: The only way to do that is to have all your tables into the same schema and do a DROP SCHEMA CASCADE. But it is a thing that I do not recommend... Having such a number of table to destroy reveal probably a fine mess about data modeling...

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe Its about only privileges.I don't want to drop any table at the moment. I just want to create a new role that can only delete tables and nothing else.But in order to do that, i should change the privilages under security in each table. Right?

Comment: Great question.  Hopefully PG will adopt this capability in the future, particularly for those usage styles where schemas serve as namespaces for organizing related tables having a shared ownership responsibility.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way you can do that easily in PostgreSQL. The only role (=user) that can drop an object is

1. the owner of the object (the role that created it)
2. a direct or indirect member of that role
3. a user with `CREATE` privilege on the schema that contains the table
4. a superuser

So the only way to have a user that can drop any table is to create a superuser or give the user `CREATE` on all schemas. A superuser can do everything else too, and you cannot restrict that. A user with `CREATE` on a schema can create arbitrary objects in it.

I think the requirement is strange, but what you could do is the following: create a `SECURITY DEFINER` function that belongs to a superuser and can drop any table, revoke the `EXECUTE` privilege from `PUBLIC` and grant it only to the desired role.

An alternative might be to use schema permissions and write an event trigger that prevents the user from doing anything but dropping objects.

Comment: This is not a strange concept at all, particularly for those coming from another DBMS like SQL Server and/or migrations from SQL Server.  Schemas are often used for namespacing purposes and are not user-bounded.  So it makes perfect sense in that context to have schema admins that can DROP tables if they are a schema admin.  The outcome of lacking this feature is an over-reliance on elevated privileges, which seems to be the opposite of PG's intent with the otherwise abundance of permissioning options.

Comment: @JonathanB.I see what you are saying. If you want schemas to be independent from permissions, you can `GRANT` both `USAGE` and `CREATE` to `PUBLIC`. Securitywise, that's a bad idea, because most privilege escalation attacks work be creating malicious objects. Perhaps SQL Server has other means to prevent users from creating objects, I have no idea. Sometimes you cannot just take the security model from one RDBMS and apply it to another one.